# Qual é a diferença entre vetores numeric e integer?

Tags: r

No R, vetores idênticos (que contém os mesmos números) podem assumir as classes `numeric` e `integer`. Por exemplo:

```
x<-(1:5)
class(x)
[1] "integer"

x<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
class(x)
[1] "numeric"
```

- Por quê isso ocorre?
- Qual vetor utilizar em detrimento de outro e, por conta de que aspecto (vantagens e desvantagens)?
- Qual é a relação de uma variável tipo `double` com estas classes anteriores?
- Há alguma conexão entre o conceito de "ponto flutuante" e estas classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Por que isso ocorre?

O `R` possui duas classes de números: integer e numeric. A classe *integer* serve apenas para registrar números inteiros, enquanto *numeric* serve para registrar números reais (embora, se eu quisesse usar uma linguagem mais precisa, o correto é dizer que são números de ponto flutuante com dupla precisão).

Por padrão, vetores construídos com `:` são *integer*, enquanto vetores construídos com `c` são construídos como *numeric*. É assim porque é assim. Era necessário escolher uma maneira de padronizar a criação de vetores. Além disso, a maioria das operações matemáticas nos computadores é feita utilizando aritmética de ponto flutuante, então fazer a função `c` criar vetores desta classe evita que vetores *integer* tenham que ser convertidos para *numeric* quanto alguma operação que não esteja definida nos inteiros tenha que ser realizada.

Entretanto, é possível utilizar a função `c` para construir um vetor com inteiros:

```
x <- c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L)
class(x)
[1] "integer"
```

O caracter `L` após um número indica ao `R` que desejamos que este número seja registrado na memória como um inteiro.

> Qual vetor utilizar em detrimento de outro? Por conta de que aspecto (vantagens e desvantagens)?

Para a imensa maioria dos casos, tanto faz. A classe *integer* ocupa menos espaço na memória:

```
x <- 1:100
object.size(x)
448 bytes
object.size(as.numeric(x))
848 bytes
```

Desta forma, talvez hajam situações extremas em que a economia causada pelo uso de *integer* se justifique, mas não é algo com o qual eu me preocuparia se meus programas estiverem rodando na memória disponível na minha máquina.

Assim, embora *integer* ocupe menos memória, esta classe não consegue representar tantos números diferentes quanto *numeric*:

```
.Machine$integer.max
[1] 2147483647
.Machine$double.xmax
1.797693e+308
```

Veja que no meu PC, o maior inteiro que o `R` consegue representar é 2147483647 (dois bilhões e pouco), enquanto o maior número de ponto flutuante é bem maior e acho que nem tem nome oficial. Este limite para os inteiros é bem fácil de verificar:

```
as.integer(2147483647)
[1] 2147483647
as.integer(2147483647+1)
[1] NA
```

Veja que até 2147483647 é possível guardar um valor inteiro na memória do `R`, mas se eu adiciono uma unidade a ele, ocorre um erro, justamente porque o limite foi ultrapassado.

Portanto, embora os inteiros ocupem menos espaço na memória, talvez não seja uma boa ideia utilizá-los caso algum cálculo passe de 2147483647 ou hajam operações matemáticas que possam sair do domínio dos inteiros, como a divisão, por exemplo.

> Qual é a relação de uma variável tipo double com estas classes anteriores? Há alguma conexão entre o conceito de "ponto flutuante" e estas classes?

Creio que eu tenha respondido esta pergunta dentro das anteriores.